# Java Constructor User Input in Main ending as Null in Constructor

Tags: java, input, constructor, null

As you may infer, I am new to Java.

I am using a Java Main and associated Constructor to calculate area, perimeter from radius. That I figured it out with static values.

I am using an input from which its value is being sent to the constructor, first as a string then I am able to cast it into a double. Using println() at specific locations, I see the string then the casted double then a Null.

The dropped value happens in between line 14 and line 23 of Cercle1 (constructor).
After searching online examples and modifying their Java code, here is what I have.

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cercle {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /////---------------------------------------
        /// USER INPUT
        String rad;
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input radius: ");
        rad = ss.nextLine();
        Cercle1 a = new Cercle1(rad);
        System.out.println("Cercle: "+rad);

        /////---------------------------------------
        Cercle1 pi = new Cercle1();
        Cercle1 radius= new Cercle1();
        Cercle1 circle= new Cercle1();
        Cercle1 perimeter = new Cercle1();

        System.out.println("PI       : "+pi.getPI());
        System.out.println("Radius   : "+radius.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Area     : "+circle.computeArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: "+perimeter.computePerimeter());
    }
}
```

Contructor:

```
public class Cercle1 {
    public double radius;

    /////---------------------------------------
    /// PASS USER INPUT
    Double rad2;

    public Cercle1(String rad) {
        rad2 = Double.valueOf(rad);
        System.out.println("Cercle1 rad2 line14: "+rad2);
    }

    /////---------------------------------------
    Cercle1() {
        System.out.println("Cercle1 rad2 line23: "+rad2);
        radius = rad2; //1.0;
        pi =  (Math.PI);
    }
    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        rad2 = radius;
    }
    private double pi;
    double getPI() {
        return pi;
    }
    double getRadius() {
        return rad2;
    }
    public double computeDiameter() {
        return rad2*2;
    }
    double computePerimeter() {
        return pi * (2 * rad2);
    }
    double computeArea() {
        return (Math.PI * Math.pow(rad2, 2));
    }
}
```

The output in the IntelliJ console:

```
Input radius: 1
Cercle1 rad2 line14: 1.0
Cercle line17 rad: 1
Cercle1 rad2 line23: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Cercle1.<init>(Cercle1.java:22)
    at Cercle.main(Cercle.java:20)
```

I see that in between line 17 and line 23 in Cercle1 my double rad2 becomes Null.
I had tried many ways to pass the value from public class Cercle1{...} to Cercle1() without success.

Question: Can you explain me what is the obvious that I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: The error is in the no-args constructor. You are setting the instance variable `radius` to the instance variable `rad2` which is still null, as you haven't initialized it yet.

Comment: I believe you do not realize that your constructors create individual instances that do not share their instance variables.

Comment: Or else you mistakenly think that `rad2` is static. It's poor design. You should delete this constructor and pass the same argument when you construct all the instances, if that's the effect you want. And you don't need two radius variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you write `new Circle1()` you create a brand new object, and it is independent from the other ones.

And when you do

```
Cercle1 pi = new Cercle1();
Cercle1 radius= new Cercle1();
Cercle1 circle= new Cercle1();
Cercle1 perimeter = new Cercle1();
```

you create 4 new `Cercle1` objects which have **no radius**. So when you try to get any calculation going that involve the radius (diameter, perimeter, area) you get a `NullPointerException` because the radius is not defined (it is null).

What you want to do is create one `Cercle` with a radius and query its getter methods.

Also you do not need a second class `Cercle1`. you only need your `Cercle` class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cercle {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // USER INPUT
        String rad;
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input radius: ");
        rad = ss.nextLine();
        Cercle myCercle = new Cercle(rad);

        // That's it, that's all you have to do, 
        // you now have a circle and you can get its area and perimeter

        System.out.println("Cercle: "+rad);
        System.out.println("PI       : "+myCercle.getPI());
        System.out.println("Radius   : "+myCercle.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Area     : "+myCercle.computeArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: "+myCercle.computePerimeter());
    }


    private Double radius;
    private Double pi = Math.PI;

    public Cercle(String rad) {
        radius = Double.valueOf(rad);
    }

    double getPI() {
        return pi;
    }
    double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public double computeDiameter() {
        return 2 * radius;
    }
    double computePerimeter() {
        return pi * 2 * radius;
    }
    double computeArea() {
        return (pi * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }
}
```

Now, when you say

> I am using a Java Main and associated Constructor

I am not sure you understand that they are not *associated*, that main does not have to be in the Cercle class. They could be in 2 different classes, in 2 different files:

```
public class MyUserInputClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // USER INPUT
        String rad;
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input radius: ");
        rad = ss.nextLine();
        Cercle myCercle = new Cercle(rad);

        // That's it, that's all you have to do, 
        // you now have a circle and you can get its area and perimeter

        System.out.println("Cercle: "+rad);
        System.out.println("PI       : "+myCercle.getPI());
        System.out.println("Radius   : "+myCercle.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Area     : "+myCercle.computeArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter: "+myCercle.computePerimeter());
    }
}
```

```
public class Cercle {

    private Double radius;
    private Double pi = Math.PI;

    public Cercle(String rad) {
        radius = Double.valueOf(rad);
    }

    double getPI() {
        return pi;
    }
    double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public double computeDiameter() {
        return 2 * radius;
    }
    double computePerimeter() {
        return pi * 2 * radius;
    }
    double computeArea() {
        return (pi * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to explain this. Much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The quick issue is that, inside the no-arg constructor, you are trying to assign the Double rad2 (which is an object) to the double radius (a primitive). rad2 has not been initialized, so it is null. When Java tries to unbox the Double, you are getting the null pointer exception. Initialize rad2 before trying to assign it to radius.

```
Cercle1() {
    System.out.println("Cercle1 rad2 line23: "+rad2);
    rad2 = 1.0;
    radius = rad2; //1.0;
    pi =  (Math.PI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to pass the input to the constructor without it becoming Null as seen in my initial code above. Took me a while to figure out the proper way. 
I want to thank all for your inputs, they helped me resolve my problem.

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cercle_v1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rad;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input radius: ");
        rad = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        Cercle1_v1 radius = new Cercle1_v1(rad);
        Cercle1_v1 dia = new Cercle1_v1(rad);
        Cercle1_v1 peri = new Cercle1_v1(rad);
        Cercle1_v1 area= new Cercle1_v1(rad);

        System.out.println("Radius      : "+radius.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Diameter    : "+dia.getDiameter());
        System.out.println("Perimeter   : "+peri.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("Area        : "+area.getArea());
    }
}
```

//-----------------------------
Constructor

```
class Cercle1_v1 {
    private String rad2;
    private double rad3;
    private double pi;
    private double dia;
    private double peri;
    private double area;

    Cercle1_v1(String rad) {
        pi = (Math.PI);
        rad2 = rad;
        rad3 = Double.parseDouble(rad2);
        dia = (rad3 * 2);
        peri = (pi * (dia));
        area = (pi * Math.pow((dia), 2))/4;
        }

    double getRadius() {
        return (rad3);
    }
    double getDiameter() {
        return (dia);
    }
    double getPerimeter() {
        return (peri);
    }
    double getArea() {
        return (area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though that works, it does not seem correct  you should not be creating all these circles. Have a look at my answer, hopefully it will clear it out